# "clr-namespace '{0}' not found" and "InitializeComponent does not exist" double issue

Tags: wpf

I am working on a WPF project in which I am encountering a vicious circle of bugs. At first, I get

```
The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace '{0}' that is not included in the assembly
```

I have been able to solve that issue  (at first), but it introduced another error:

```
The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
```

However, solving that issue causes the first one again. The relevant XAML code looks like this (simplified):

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Main_Namespace"
        Title="Client" WindowState="Maximized" MinWidth="800" MinHeight="600">

</Window>
```

Note that my main namespace actually has a space in it.... Maybe that that is causing the errors? I know Visual Studio (and any other code editor for that matter) is quite picky on how you name your files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is no longer linked to your code behind (hence no InitializeComponent), you have somehow managed to kill the [`x:Class` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752309.aspx). Not sure what to do about the spaces though...

Comment: That seemed to work. It compiles just fine... I now get a System.NotImplementedException on the constructor of a class that uses a default constructor... >.>

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I copied XAML files from one project to another. You need to set these xaml files to "Page" in the file properties. IntializeCompounent is generated, in the Window.xaml.g.cs, if the xaml-compiler runs.